# Faster pressing of keys than events in pygame

Tags: pygame, keystroke

I'm trying to create program using pygame to store the hold time and time intervals between successive keys.

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                show_times()
            t1 = time.time()
            char = pygame.key.name(event.key)
            char_list.append(pygame.key.name(event.key))
            update_screen()
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            t2 = time.time()
            if pygame.key.name(event.key) == char:
                holdtimes[char] = [t1,t2,(t2 - t1)]
                //for debugging
                print holdtimes.keys()
```

This code works fine when user presses keys relatively slow but however when keys are typed faster it misses some keys. How can I make it work when typing is faster?

Answer (score 0):

How often are you calling the function with this code in? If you set a clock (pygame.time.clock ()) and call clock.tick (200) this will update 200 times per second.